# Dynamical size of textarea

Tags: javascript, html, size, codemirror

I'm using [CodeMirror 2](http://codemirror.net/2/manual.html) editor. The trouble is that I can't make it fullsize (100%; 100%). I added to the main style:

```
.CodeMirror {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And this doesn't work for me in any browser. Any ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the following code in http://jsbin.com to stretch the CodeMirror frame (note that JS Bin in particular stretches to half screen width, but the example code below does "fullscreen"):

```
.CodeMirror {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

I don't remember whether CodeMirror adds the class by default, but if it doesn't, you'll also want to add it in the JavaScript (assuming you've not solved this already):

```
CodeMirror.fromTextArea('ID_OF_TEXTAREA', {
  // .. some other options...
  iframeClass: 'CodeMirror'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with CSS, instead you can use JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var oTextarea = document.getElementById("myText");
    var oParent = oTextarea.parentNode;
    oTextarea.style.width = (oParent.scrollWidth - 30) + "px";
    oTextarea.style.height = (oParent.scrollHeight - 30) + "px";
};
```

This will set the size of the `textarea` based on its parent size.
Added some "padding" but you can remove or reduce it.

Comment: @Ock - how is the textarea defined? Does it have ID at all? Parent element? It worked for me in quick test I pulled.

Comment: Worked with CodeMirror? Because it wraps textarea with his own divs.

Comment: @Ock no, with plain `textarea` - you'll have to find the ID of the textarea and use it instead of "myText" in the example.

Comment: I understand, but this doesn't work with CodeMirror, and question is codemirror-related :)

Comment: This works in general, just assumed you can get direct access to the generated textarea element - sorry for that! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body, .container, .subContainer, .CodeMirror {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Should work as well.